# Verifying a RSA signature made by Crypto Node.JS in C#

Tags: c#, node.js, rsa, signing

I'm trying to build a web service using *Express/NodeJS* which signs a piece of information. The signed data is received and verified by a client written in *C#*. You'll have to forgive my inexperience in cryptography and its associated technologies.

First off, I generate a **certificate** for the *C# client* and a **private key** for the *NodeJS application* using *OpenSSL*;

> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days
> 365

In the *NodeJS application*, I have the following code;

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const fs = require('fs')

var pem = fs.readFileSync('./keys/key.pem');
var key = pem.toString('ascii');
var privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
    'key': key,
    'format': 'pem',
    'passphrase': '<PASSPHRASE>',
});

function sign(identifier){
    var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
    sign.update(identifier);
    var sig = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
    return sig;
}

exports.sign = sign;
```

In this case, the parameter `identifier` is the data to be signed. The client will receive this, and the signature generated, `sig`.

In the C# client I have the following snippet;

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(pub));
using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    using (var rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
    {
        bool results = rsa.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        Console.WriteLine(results.ToString());
    }
}
```

The `pub` is the generated certificate in Base64, it is stored in a `const string`. The `data` contains the same information as `identifier` in the NodeJS application, but it's converted to bytes using `Convert.FromBase64String(...)`, and likewise the `signature` is the data returned from `sig` in the NodeJS application, only converted from Base64 to byte data.

When all information is inserted, `VerifyData()` returns false, this leads me to believe that there's some kind of missmatch between the cryptographic configurations of the web service and the client.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually when there are issues with RSA going between c# and JSON it is the padding mode.  The default padding mode is different in c# than JSON.

Comment: Why is `data` in the C# code Base64 decoded? In the NodeJS code this doesn't happen, there `identifier` is UTF8 encoded (by default since no explicit encoding is specified in `update()`). The C# counterpart would be `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`.

Comment: I don't think padding is the problem, since `sign.sign()` applies PKCS1 v1.5 padding by default, which is also used in the C# code.

Comment: @Topaco That was the problem, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem was that `data` in the C# client was converted to from Base64 when the data in the NodeJS application read from UTF-8.

The solution was to convert the string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`

Thanks for the quick response!